# inserting new value to an array of object in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

How do we insert a  value to an array of object in typescript ?

I wanna insert 1993 value to each annualRentCurrent value on the sample object.

So each annualRentCurrent value would be now 1993. Any idea guys? . How do we address this in typescript or in angular ? Thanks.

#data I wanna insert

```
this.transaction.propertyDto.propertyDetailDto.annualRentUsd = 1993;
```

#sample object

```
   this.data.object = [
        {
            "id": 196,
            "name": "Partner Deal ",
            "dealType": "Partner Location Submission",
            "annualRentProposed": null,
            "annualRentCurrent": null,
            "firmTermRemaining": null,
            "firmTermAdded": null,
            "maxAvailableTerm": null,
            "capitalContribution": null,
            "createdOnString": "09/30/2021",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        },
        {
            "id": 197,
            "name": "Buyout Deal Disposition",
            "dealType": "Idle Buyout",
            "annualRentProposed": null,
            "annualRentCurrent": null,
            "firmTermRemaining": null,
            "firmTermAdded": null,
            "maxAvailableTerm": null,
            "capitalContribution": null,
            "createdOnString": "09/30/2021",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        },
        {
            "id": 199,
            "name": "Sublease Deal Disposition",
            "dealType": "Idle Sublease",
            "annualRentProposed": null,
            "annualRentCurrent": null,
            "firmTermRemaining": null,
            "firmTermAdded": null,
            "maxAvailableTerm": null,
            "capitalContribution": null,
            "createdOnString": "09/30/2021",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        },
        {
            "id": 203,
            "name": "Disposition of Location #10532-S",
            "dealType": "PM Restructure",
            "annualRentProposed": null,
            "annualRentCurrent": null,
            "firmTermRemaining": null,
            "firmTermAdded": null,
            "maxAvailableTerm": null,
            "capitalContribution": null,
            "createdOnString": "10/01/2021",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        },
        {
            "id": 214,
            "name": null,
            "dealType": "Approval to Close",
            "annualRentProposed": null,
            "annualRentCurrent": null,
            "firmTermRemaining": null,
            "firmTermAdded": null,
            "maxAvailableTerm": null,
            "capitalContribution": null,
            "createdOnString": "10/04/2021",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        },
        {
            "id": 215,
            "name": "pmpm",
            "dealType": "PM Restructure",
            "annualRentProposed": null,
            "annualRentCurrent": null,
            "firmTermRemaining": null,
            "firmTermAdded": null,
            "maxAvailableTerm": null,
            "capitalContribution": null,
            "createdOnString": "10/05/2021",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        }
    ]
```

Comment: How about using the filter operator of RxJs? https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're just wanting to set the same value across all elements in the array, you can just use `map`:

```
this.data.object.map(o => o.annualRentCurrent = 1993);
```

or `forEach`:

```
this.data.object.forEach(o => o.annualRentCurrent = 1993);
```

They're basically identical in this scenario, but `map` will return a new array (and in this case also altering the original) while forEach just iterates over each element in the original array.

Comment: Hi Sir, what If I wanna make it 2 Sir like annualRentCurrent = 1993 and annualRentProposed = 1994 , how do we do that in a map ?

Comment: `this.data.object.map(o => o.annualRentProposed= 1994);`

Comment: @NikhilVS , so you have to repeat the code everytime you want to modify one ?

Comment: @BrindaAnand It all depends on exactly what you want. If you're trying to increment the value each time you could do something like: `let val = 1993; this.data.object.map(o => o.annualRentCurrent = val++);` and then you'll get numbers from 1993-1999. You could also call an external method like `this.data.object.map(o => o.annualRentCurrent = getAnnualRent(o);` and you can calculate it based on the object. There are tons of ways to solve this dependent on exactly what you want.

Comment: No, the two lines would do the things. As @Mordred said, there are many ways depending on your logic and convenience.

Comment: what If I add multiple values , then I have to always repeat this.data.object.map ?

Comment: @Mordred No Sir , I am not trying to increment